# RedirectStandardInput has no effect for powershell remote execution

Tags: c#, powershell, input, process

I'm trying to redirect input for powershell.exe remote execution.

And it gives me next output:

> Windows PowerShell  Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Host  receive failed 10054

So looks like it calls powershell, but next commands are not passed as input, nothing happens, so Process exited with timeout.

Why? Does PowerShell has some specific input, so it can't be launched like this? Any workarounds?

PS executed like next:

```
RemoteExecute.ExecutePowerShell(testPSName, testIp, testUserName, testPasswd);
```

ExecutePowerShell:

```
FTPTransfer.SendBinary(shellScriptName, ipaddress, userName, password); // This one sends script to remote system. Works OK.
string fullFilePath = "\"" + FTPTransfer.UploadDirectoryRootPath + shellScriptName + "\"";

string cmd;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
                //sw.WriteLine("powershell.exe"); // Tried launch remexec with cmd, and then pass powershell as first parameter. Results the same, as now, so no matter.
                sw.WriteLine("Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
                sw.WriteLine(fullFilePath);

                cmd = sw.ToString();
}
result = ExecutePSCommandWithInput(cmd, ipaddress, userName, password);
```

ExecutePSCommandWithInput:

```
//command = cmd from ExecutePowerShell
string remexecCmd = "remexec.exe";
string remexecArgs = string.Format("{0} -q -t {1} -l {2} -p {3} powershell.exe 2>&1", ipaddress, timeout, userName, password);
result = Common.ExecuteCmdWithInput(remexecCmd, remexecArgs, command, out outp, timeout);
```

ExecuteCmdWithInput:

```
public static int ExecuteCmdWithInput(string mainCmd, string arguments, string commands, out string output, int timeout = 60000)
        {
            List<string> commandsArr = new List<string>();
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(commands))
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    commandsArr.Add(line);
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            return ExecuteCmdWithInput(mainCmd, arguments, commandsArr.ToArray(), out output, timeout);
        }
public static int ExecuteCmdWithInput(string mainCmd, string arguments, string[] commands, out string output, int timeout = 60000)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = mainCmd;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            p.Start();
            using (StreamWriter inputWriter = p.StandardInput)
            {
                foreach(string line in commands)
                {
                    inputWriter.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }

            output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            output += Environment.NewLine;
            output += p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit(timeout);

            return p.ExitCode;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't use standard input or output, so I had to use workaround, or different implementation.

Solved like this:

```
string remexecArgs = string.Format("{0} -q -t {1} -l {2} -p {3} cmd 2>&1", ipaddress, timeout, userName, password);
```

and as input passed next:

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
   sw.WriteLine("powershell.exe -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
   sw.WriteLine();
   string logFilePath = "\"" + FTPTransfer.UploadDirectoryRootPath + shellScriptName + ".log\"";
   sw.WriteLine("powershell.exe -File " + fullFilePath + " " + (pars ?? string.Empty) + "> " + logFilePath);
   sw.WriteLine();
   sw.WriteLine();
   sw.WriteLine("type " + logFilePath);

   cmd = sw.ToString();
}
ExecuteOneCommandWithInput(cmd, ipaddress, userName, password, timeoutS);
```

Empty lines are nesesery, otherwise it stucks

And small hack added to process itself:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = mainCmd;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
p.Start();
using (StreamWriter inputWriter = p.StandardInput)
{
   foreach(string line in commands)
   {
      //Wait before next input in case when empty string passed
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 2);

      inputWriter.WriteLine(line);
   }
}
output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
output += Environment.NewLine;
output += p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit(timeout);
```